# failed in running flutter on MacOS

Tags: flutter

I Search a-lot for answer put  ,
This is my output :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      path_provider_macos.PathProviderPlugin.handle(_: __C.FlutterMethodCall, result: (Any?) -> ()) -> () in PathProviderPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PathProviderPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** BUILD FAILED **

Exception: Build process failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try arch -x86_64 pod install and then try building it

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Ha e you implemented all configuration for path provider package?

Comment: I Wasn't on channel beta so I Switch to channel beta and it work

Comment: and redownload flutter SDK